# Does The Bible speak about One Holy Spirit or more?

Tags: greek, word-study

While reading the Bible I have noticed The Holy Spirit seems to be referred to by different names. Grammatically speaking and contextually speaking are these various words referring to The Same Spirit?

Acts 16:7
And when they came to the border of Mysia, they tried to enter Bithynia, but the Spirit of Jesus would not permit them.

Romans 8:9
You, however, are not in the realm of the flesh but are in the realm of the Spirit, if indeed the Spirit of God lives in you. And if anyone does not have the Spirit of Christ, they do not belong to Christ.

John 14:17
the Spirit of truth. The world cannot receive Him, because it neither sees Him nor knows Him. But you do know Him, for He abides with you and will be in you

Comment: This is a theological synthesis question, and so not really on-topic here. Some people think all those verses are referring to a distinct personal Holy Spirit, others think that it is not distinct or not personal.

Comment: Why is this closed? The question asks about the interpretation of the text, and includes the texts in question.

Comment: @Biblasia I explained exactly why in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

These are references to one Spirit, described in different ways. The quick succession of statements in Romans 8v9 shows that they are two different ways of saying the same thing. The Spirit of God is the Spirit that belongs to Christ.

The best way of understanding the relationship is to go through the statements about the Spirit in the last discourse of John's gospel, where we see the different angles. In ch14 vv16-17, the Father gives the Counsellor, who is also the Spirit of truth, in response to the prayer of Jesus. v26, the Father sends the Spirit "in my name". But in ch15 v26, it Jesus who sends the Counsellor or Spirit of truth "from the Father". And in ch16 v7 "If I go, I will send him to you", and in ch16 v14 part of the function of the spirit of truth is to "glorify me" by speaking of Christ, which is the vital aspect of the "all truth" into which the Spirit will guide them. In short, the Spirit is sent in different ways by Father and Son and belongs to both of them.

Comment: The spirit is called the "comforter" (parakletos) in four places.  In the only remaining place where the Greek "parakletos" is used, it names our comforter as "Jesus Christ."  Unfortunately, translators decided to use "advocate" there instead, obscuring the identification.  See 1 John 2:1 in Greek and compare to John 14:26, etc.

Comment: Quite so. Your point helps to demonstrate how much the Spirit is "of Jesus Christ". In a sense, the Spirit is his representative.